# Kihara-like Z/6Z elliptic curve families

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, rational-points

Shoichi Kihara constructed a family of elliptic curves with Mordell–Weil group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}^3$ (generic rank at least 3) in 2006. Kihara's family produces a number of [rank 8](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/z6old678.html) curves.

> S. Kihara, *On the rank of the elliptic curves with a rational point of order 6*, Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci., Volume 82, Number 7 (2006), 81-82, doi:10.3792/pjaa.82.81, [1160485501](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1160485501)

> A. Dujella, J.C. Peral, P. Tadić, *Elliptic curves with torsion group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$*, Glas. Mat. Ser. III 51 (2016), 321-333 doi:[10.3336/gm.51.2.03](https://doi.org/10.3336/gm.51.2.03), [1503.03667](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03667)

Kihara's family is described by a function $c(t)$ and produces $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ elliptic curves $E$ by the following recipe:

(1) $c = c(t) = \dfrac{-(2t+1)(t-7)(t+2)(4t-7)}{(4t^2+13t+1)(2t^2-91t+98)}$

$A = \dfrac{1+6c-3c^2}{4}$, $B = -c^3$, $E$ = EllipticCurve([0,$A$,0,$B$,0])

Looking at (1), I was able to generalize the function $c(t)$ to produce Kihara-like families dependent on a set of parameters $(r,p,b)$ in the following manner:

(2) $c=c(t)=\dfrac{-(rt+2)(t-p)(t+2)(rt-p)}{r^2t^4+2bt^3+2(2rp+kb)t^2-\frac{4pb}{r}t+4p^2}$, where $k=\dfrac{-p^2+\frac{2p}{r}(r^2+4r+1)-4}{(r+1)(p-2)}$

Then original Kihara's family is generated by the set of parameters:

(3) $(r,p,b)=(4,7,-338)$, and for its respective 2-isogenous family $(r,p,b)=(4,-1,15)$

Trying different sets of parameters $(r,p,b)$ in SageMath, I was able to find two more families with generic rank at least 3. Both of them, same as Kihara's, could be presented with $r=4$. (Note that there is a total of 24 different sets of parameters $(r,p,b)$ resulting in 12 different formulas for $c(t)$, all of which produce the same family of curves $E$).

(4) $(r,b,p)=(4,10,-320)$, and for its respective 2-isogenous family $(r,p,b)=(4,-6/7,8/7)$

(5) $(r,b,p)=(4,-18,968)$, and for its respective 2-isogenous family $(r,p,b)=(4,-14,40)$

I was also able to find an infinite number of families with Mordell–Weil group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}^2$ (generic rank at least 2), the most productive of which in terms of high rank curves is probably

(6) $(r,p,b)=(-a,\frac{2(9a+1)}{a+1},\frac{8a(a-1)}{a+1})$, where $a\ne-1,-\frac{1}{9},0,1$

**My questions:**

1. Is it possible to find a new Kihara-like family (2) with generic rank at least 3? I am offering a bounty of $50$ for a set of parameters $(r,p,b)$ that generates a family not equivalent to (3)-(5) or their 2-isogenies.
2. Can the families (2) with Mordell–Weil group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}^3$ always be presented with $r=4$? I am offering a bounty of $50$ for proving or disproving this statement.
3. Is it possible to find a value $a$ in (6) that produces a curve in (2) with [rank 9](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/z6.html) for some $t$? Note that there are only [two](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/z6.html) known rank 9 $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ curves to date, and they don't seem to fit (6).

**Disclaimer:** Any and all of rank 8-9 curves obtained from the answers will be credited to you, not to me.

**Edit:** I offer \$$50$ Canadian for the first answer to each of the questions above. That would be a total pool of \$$150$ Canadian.

Comment: I would guess that the state of the art of that question would most likely be mentioned in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.00077.pdf which from a quick look seems to reference only Kihara. So I think this is not known. Of course, someone might find it on this question...

Comment: @Will Sawin: Thank you for mentioning the 2020 "New Rank Records" paper! This paper published as part of ANTS XIV (https://msp.org/obs/2020/4-1/obs-v4-n1-p15-s.pdf) does mention my rank 9 curve from a ℤ/6ℤ×ℤ^2 family in a remark on p. 236 (p. 5 in a PDF). That curve was not generated by using formula (6) above. As many, I too was looking for rank 9 in the known ℤ/6ℤ×ℤ^3 families (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03667.pdf for their great analysis), found none, and came to the same conclusion as the paper authors, that "the number of high-rank specializations in [them] decayed rapidly".